# Show that closure of a set is intersection of the set and closed balls

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I need to show that:

$$cl(C) = C \cup \partial C = \bigcap_{r > 0; x \in C} B(x,r)$$

where $cl$, $\partial$ is the closure and boundary of set $C$, and $B(x,r)$ is the closed ball centered on $x$ with radius r.

How can i define this intersection on the most right side?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I assume you meant union instead of addition, so I edited your post.

Comment: Hello @Math1000, on the file I'm reading there's an addition symbol. I thought it was weird so i decided to ask, because it might be a specific notation. While no one answer I'll try to develop the proof, using union instead. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Well, that,s not true.  Let C=(-1,1) then the C $\cap $B (0,1/2)=C and the intersection is C. (And what if 0 is not in C at all, or even in the space?  And why 0?  Why not any other point?) I think you mean $\cap_{r>0;x\in C}B (x,r) $.

Comment: What space is this in.

Comment: @fleablood It's on $R^n$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean the right side to be $$\bigcap_{r>0} B(C,r) = \bigcap_{r>0}  \bigg( \bigcup_{x\in C} B(x,r) \bigg).$$

Comment: Um, don't trust *me* to know what you problem says.  It occurs to me now that what I wrote isn't true either.  Obviously.  So what *is* the problem as stated in the file you are reading?

Comment: @GregMartin given your correction, the union wouldn't be 'larger' than $C$ ? (given that $r > 0$) .

Comment: @fleablood In the file, it says: "Show that: $cl(C) = C \cup \partial C = \cap_{r > 0} [C + B(0,r)]$". I think that the  $B(0,r)$ part is really wrong(maybe the person who wrote the exercise wanted to say the closed ball translated to the origin, but lacked information).

Comment: Yes.  In that case the + makes perfect sense and it never should have been edited out. A+B ={a+b|a in A; b in B}.  So C + B (0,r) can be thought of as extending the border of C out by r.  What it actually is is the set of all points c of C with all the points within r of c included and then the intersection of those sets for smaller rs.

Comment: And, for goodness sake, just because some idiots on the Internet say you wrote down a problem wrong, doesn't mean you did.  *you* are the one who has the problem in front of you and knows what it says.  What you had originally was what the problem was.  What Math1000 edited it to and what I told you it was and what you have now is utter *garbage*.  Why on earth did you listen to us when had the problem in front if you.

Comment: If x is in the intersection but not in C then for every r there is B(c,r) with x in it.  Which means ever B (x,r) contains a c in it.  So x is limit point.  So the intersection is a subset of the closure.  So that's half.

Comment: Great, note that $\bigcap_{r>0} (C+B(0,r))$ is actually the same as what I wrote—so we agree!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\overline{C} = C \cup \partial C$.

$B(0,r) = \{x \in \mathbb R^n|d(0,x) \le r\}$

$C + B(0,r) = \{x + y|x \in C; y \in B(0,r)\}=\{x \in X|\exists c\in C; d(c,x) \le r\}$

Let $x \in C$ then $x \in \cap_{r > 0}[C + B(0,r)]$

Let $x \in \partial C$. The $x$ is a limit point of $C$.  So for every $r$ there is a $c$ so that $d(c,x) < r$.  So $x \in C + B(0,r) = \{x + y|x \in C; y \in B(0,r)\}=\{x \in X|\exists c\in C; d(c,x) \le r\}$ for all $r$.

So $x \in \cap_{r > 0}[C + B(0,r)]$

So $\overline C \subset \cap_{r > 0}[C + B(0,r)]$.

If $x \in \cap_{r > 0}[C + B(0,r)]$ either $x \in C$ or $x \not \in C$.  If $x \not \in C$ then for any $r_1> r > 0, x \in C + B(0,r)$ meaning that there is some $c \ne x$ such that $d(x,c) \le r < r_1$.  So $x$ is a limit point of $C$.

So if $x \in \cap_{r > 0}[C + B(0,r)]$ either $x \in C$ or $x \in \partial C$.

So $\cap_{r > 0}[C + B(0,r)]\subset \overline{C}$.

So $\overline{C}=\cap_{r > 0}[C + B(0,r)]$.